# The intent-filter of the activity must contain android.intent.aciton.MAIN action

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest

"The intent-filter of the activity must contain android.intent.aciton.MAIN action" I get this output trying to run android project in Intelij.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.android_app"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name=".DashboardActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--  Login Activity -->
        <activity
                android:label="Login Account"
                android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>

    </application>

    <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Does anyone has an idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

Already found an answer. Problem was with wrong class passed in run configuration. It was `com.example.android_app.LoginActivity` instead `com.example.android_app.DashboardActivity` . Hope any1 find it usefull.